# "Unfortunately, App has stopped" After clicking the Item in ListView to Fragment Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-tablayout, virtual-reality

I'm a beginner for doing this application and I encounter this problem after I put Listview in Tab Activity. In Listview there are items are onclick to go for the new activity (That activity is fragment) for VR Panorama View I will display the codes and logcat.

**ImageLoaderTask**

```
package com.example.computer.vratdragfinal;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<AssetManager, Void, Bitmap> {

    private static final String TAG = "ImageLoaderTask";
    private final String assetName;
    private final WeakReference<VrPanoramaView> viewReference;
    private final VrPanoramaView.Options viewOptions;

    private static WeakReference<Bitmap> lastBitmap = new WeakReference<>(null);
    private static String lastName;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(AssetManager... params) {
        AssetManager assetManager = params[0];

        if (assetName.equals(lastName) && lastBitmap.get() != null) {
            return lastBitmap.get();
        }

        try(InputStream istr = assetManager.open(assetName)) {
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
            lastBitmap = new WeakReference<>(b);
            lastName = assetName;
            return b;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not decode default bitmap: " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        final VrPanoramaView vw = viewReference.get();
        if (vw != null && bitmap != null) {
            vw.loadImageFromBitmap(bitmap, viewOptions);
        }
    }

    public ImageLoaderTask(VrPanoramaView view, VrPanoramaView.Options viewOptions, String assetName) {
        viewReference = new WeakReference<>(view);
        this.viewOptions = viewOptions;
        this.assetName = assetName;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.computer.vratdragfinal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        assert tabLayout != null;
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.welcome));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.venue));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return new WelcomeFragment();
                    case 1:
                        return new ttsd();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 2;
            }
        };
        assert viewPager != null;
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void refreshNow() {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        startActivity(getIntent());
        overridePendingTransition(0,0);

    }

}
```

**toptourist1**

```
package com.example.computer.vratdragfinal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView;

public class toptourist1 extends Fragment {

    private VrPanoramaView panoWidgetView;
    private ImageLoaderTask backgroundImageLoaderTask;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_toptourist1, container,false);
        panoWidgetView = (VrPanoramaView) v.findViewById(R.id.pano_view);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        panoWidgetView.pauseRendering();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        panoWidgetView.resumeRendering();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        panoWidgetView.shutdown();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private synchronized void loadPanoImage() {
        ImageLoaderTask task = backgroundImageLoaderTask;
        if (task != null && !task.isCancelled()) {
            task.cancel(true);
        }

        VrPanoramaView.Options viewOptions = new VrPanoramaView.Options();
        viewOptions.inputType = VrPanoramaView.Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;

        String panoImageName = "sample_converted.jpg";

        task = new ImageLoaderTask(panoWidgetView, viewOptions, panoImageName);
        task.execute(getActivity().getAssets());
        backgroundImageLoaderTask = task;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        loadPanoImage();
    }

}
```

**ttsd**

```
package com.example.computer.vratdragfinal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class ttsd extends Fragment {


    public ttsd() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ttsd, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        String[] awayStrings = {
                "Tubbataha Reef",
                "San Agustin Church",
                "Mayon Volcano",
                "Malapascua Island",
                "Puerto Galera",
                "Puerto Princesa Undergound River",
                "Donsol",
                "Banaue Rice Terraces",

        };

        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> lva = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, awayStrings);
        lv.setAdapter(lva);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if(position==0) {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), toptourist1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_away);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).refreshNow();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Refresh Layout working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
        );

        return view;
    }

}
```

**ViewPageAdapter**

```
package com.example.computer.vratdragfinal;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragments (Fragment fragments,String tabTitles){
        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitles.add(tabTitles);
    }

    public ViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }
}

**WelcomeFragment**

package com.example.computer.vratdragfinal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView;

public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private VrPanoramaView panoWidgetView;
    private ImageLoaderTask backgroundImageLoaderTask;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment, container,false);
        panoWidgetView = (VrPanoramaView) v.findViewById(R.id.pano_view);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        panoWidgetView.pauseRendering();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        panoWidgetView.resumeRendering();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        panoWidgetView.shutdown();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private synchronized void loadPanoImage() {
        ImageLoaderTask task = backgroundImageLoaderTask;
        if (task != null && !task.isCancelled()) {
            task.cancel(true);
        }

        VrPanoramaView.Options viewOptions = new VrPanoramaView.Options();
        viewOptions.inputType = VrPanoramaView.Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;

        String panoImageName = "converted.jpg";

        task = new ImageLoaderTask(panoWidgetView, viewOptions, panoImageName);
        task.execute(getActivity().getAssets());
        backgroundImageLoaderTask = task;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        loadPanoImage();
    }

}
```

**Run**

```
02/13 16:35:13: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.computer.vratdragfinal/com.example.computer.vratdragfinal.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 7627 on device emulator-5554
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae834b80: ver 2 0
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
W/SdkConfigurationReader: VrParamsProvider returned null params, using defaults.
D/ConfigUtils: Parameters file not found for reading: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/Cardboard/current_device_params: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
I/GVR: [vr/gvr/capi/src/gvr.cc:94] Initialized GVR version 1.10.0
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.computer.vratdragfinal, PID: 7627
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.computer.vratdragfinal/com.example.computer.vratdragfinal.toptourist1}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.computer.vratdragfinal.toptourist1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.computer.vratdragfinal.toptourist1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: You cannot go into activity from  fragment.

Comment: Its Fragment listview to new fragment. But if I try the activity it not crash but when I used the fragment the crash will appear. Whats wrong in my codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply say here Activity is a fragment and can not redirect from one fragment to another using Intent. Intent is used to switch between activities. That's the reason behind the crash. Either use the mechanism by which you can redirect to fragment or if you want to use `intent`, you need to use activity instead of fragment.

Comment: You can't just say here Activity is a fragment and can not redirect from one fragment to another using Intent. Intent is used to switch between activities. That's the reason behind the crash. Either use the mechanism by which you can redirect to fragment or if you want to use intent, you need to use activity instead of fragment. 

*Wrong click instead of comment I click edit.

Comment: There's any solution about this crash? I try to use activity but some of the codes will not work. @Srushti

Comment: What exactly you want do? I mean do you required to open another tab on the click of the list item of another tab? ideally you should open another actvity on the click of the list item from the fragment. Or another thing you can do is replace the listing fragment with the one you want to open. Or on the click of the list item you can give a callback and open another tab that you want to redirect.

Comment: Hmmm. I have two tabs in "mainactivity" the "ttsd" and " welcomefragment"

Comment: If I change the fragment to activity some of the codes will affected.